# how to store the database result in an array in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I fetched the result with query in cakephp in controller and save it in a variable when i echo the variable in view it display only "Array".No data is displayed so how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

$var = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Model.id'=>$id)));

try using:

```
var_dump($var);
```

or

```
print_r($var);
```

or perhaps even better:

```
debug($var);
```

to see the result of your query.